# Can a same phy be used for IPV6 and IPV4?

Tags: integrated-circuit, design, ethernet, phy, ipv6

Currently I am using LAN8720 from microchip in my device for IPV4 network?Can same PHY work with IPV6 network?
If yes the why?
and if no then what can anyone suggest me a decent chip for it?
Thanks

Comment: The IP layer doesn't care in the slightest what PHY you use. Remember that IP doesn't even have to be running on Ethernet - it could be WiFi or even PPP over a serial port, so the question is meaningless. Its a bit like asking 'can i put leather seats in my car which runs on diesel?' ...

Comment: @brhans: Just because the answer is plain 'yes' doesn't mean the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes you can use your phy chip. Whether you can use the other components of your system depends on what those components are.

Long answer.

Networking with IP over ethernet is a system of layers (most other network systems are too but the details of the layers will vary).

Note: I have included OSI layer numbers as they are the most common way to reffer to the layers but IP doesn't exactly fit the OSI model.

Note2: there are some simplifications in the description below to avoid clouding it with too many irrelevent details. For example I have ignored the issues of bridging, firewalls, routing and fragmentation. I have also assumed that all packets are using the "Ethernet II" frame format.

Closest to the wire we have the implemention of the physical layer encodings (OSI layer 1). These handle turning a stream of data units into something that can be transmitted on on the wire and turning the wire-encoding of incoming data into a stream of data units. They also produce and interpret special encodings that mark the start and end of frames and allow the receiver to syncronise to the incoming data. This is what your phy chip does, it just handles the wire level encoding, it doesn't care what the data means.

Next we have the medium access controller (OSI level 2). This handles taking frames from a buffer and sending them at wire-rate to the phy. It also handles receiving frames from the phy, filtering them by destination MAC address and placing them in a buffer. If the interface is in half duplex mode the MAC implements the CSMA/CD protocol. In an embedded system using a phy chip like the one you mentioned this will usually be implemnted as a perhipheral inside your microcontroller/SoC.

This is usually the point where implementation moves from hardware to software. On a system running a full-feature operating system (linux, windows etc) the driver for the MAC device will pass frames between the operating system and the MAC device. The operating system in turn will pass frames between the driver and the implementations of higher level protocols.

The operating system will normally decide which higher level protocol to send incoming frames to based on the ethertype field. Frames with an IPv4 ethertype will be sent to the IPv4 implementation and frames with an IPv6 ethertype will be sent to the ipv6 implementation. At some point the ethernet headers will also be strippped off.

Outgoing packets will have to have ethernet headers generated before they are passed to the MAC chip. This will involve looking up the MAC address of the destination device, for IPv4 this process is handled by a protocol called arp for ipv6 it is handled by a procol called neighbour discovery.

The IP (v4 or v6) implementation (OSI layer 3) will check that packets are destined for the IP address of the local system, check what protocol they are for and pass them up the stack.

Then you have protocols like TCP and UDP (OSI layer 4). These handle deciding what socket the data is for. TCP also provides a numebr of other features which I won't go into here because they aren't relavent.

And finally you have your application (OSI layer 7)

On a microcontroller implemention the lines get blurrier. There is no real operating system so vendors generall provide a "TCP/IP" stack that covers all the layers. Unfortunately microcontroller vendors were slow in adding IPv6 support to their stacks but it looks like microchip at least have now got their act together.